# python and pandas - how to access a column using iterrows

Tags: python, pandas

wowee.....how to use iterrows with python and pandas?  If I do a row iteration should I not be able to access a col with row['COL_NAME']?

Here are the col names:

```
print df
Int64Index: 152 entries, 0 to 151
Data columns:
Date          152  non-null values
Time          152  non-null values
Time Zone     152  non-null values
Currency      152  non-null values
Event         152  non-null values
Importance    152  non-null values
Actual        127  non-null values
Forecast      86  non-null values
Previous      132  non-null values
dtypes: object(9)

for row in df.iterrows():
    print row['Date']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/calandar.py", line 34, in <module>
    print row['Date']
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

if I print 1 row:

```
(0, Date                                                 Sun Apr 13
Time                                                      17:30
Time Zone                                                   GMT
Currency                                                    USD
Event         USD Fed's Stein Speaks on Financial Stability ...
Importance                                                  Low
Actual                                                      NaN
Forecast                                                    NaN
Previous                                                    NaN
Name: 0)
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

`iterrows` gives you `(index, row)` tuples rather than just the rows, so you should be able to access the columns in basically the same way you were thinking if you just do:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print row['Date']
```

Comment: Have you ever encountered a situation where `row['Date']` returns a Series representation of that single column, instead of the value itself? I'm getting that now, even though accessing the same cell from the dataframe, outside of the `iterrows()` behaves as expected.

Comment: That is the default behavior. To avoid that, try itertuples instead of iterrows.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html#pandas.DataFrame.itertuples

Answer (score 3):

If you want to iterate across your database and apply a function to each row, you might also want to consider the apply function

```
def print_row(r):
    print r['Date']

df.apply(print_row, axis = 1)
```