# Why do you need to put index, row in data frame.iterrows() in pandas when using a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to run this code:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv("data.csv")
for row in data.iterrows():
    print(row["column_title"])
```

I kept getting a TypeError:

```
 File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
   print(row["column_title_1"])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Questions about iterrows on stackoverflow used this:

```
for index, row in data.iterrows()
```

Why do you have to add that in order for the code to work?


Comment: Change `print(row["column_title"]` to `print(row)` to see why. `iterrows()` yields tuples (row_number, row_values), similar to `enumerate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) returns a `tuple` containing the `index` and the `Series` of the row, as stated by the documentation.

> Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs.

If you want to access the Series, you need to first unpack the result of `data.iterrows()` by using the unpacking syntax that you've mentioned.

Comment: For more information, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23146038/4713169)